# Appending rows to make matrix in python from text file

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix, text-files

I have a text file with a matrix in this form: http://textuploader.com/d0qmb
Each integer must occupy its own spot in the matrix. I have written this code that allows me to print arrays for each row in the matrix, but I have no idea how to append each array to create a matrix.

```
import numpy as np

# rows, cols not used in code. Just for info
rows = 9
cols = 93

with open('bob.txt') as f:
 while True:
    i=0
    str = f.readline()
    str = str.strip()
    d = list(str)
    d = map(int, d)
    if not str: break
    print(d)
    i += 1
```

Comment: create a list and use append to append a list inside that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

array = []
with open('bob.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        array.append(array.append([int(i) for i in list(line) if i.isdigit()]))

numpy_array = np.array(array)
```

`[int(i) for i in list(line) if i.isdigit()]` is [a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in python.

It's roughly the same thing as:

```
for character in line:
    if character is:
        cast this character to an int and append it to the list
```

Comment: I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Are you using something other than the provided example? Are there floats involved?

Comment: No, I'm using the text file I provided.

Comment: Oh,you've got spaces that didn't show up for me. One second I'll fix it

Comment: @rajkarthikkumar I've fixed the issue, it works on my end. Does it work for you now?